# How do I change the Java version of my "installed project facet" in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, google-app-engine

I just installed Eclipse 3.7 and the Google Plugin for Eclipse because I want to teach myself how to use Google App Engine.

When I create a new web application and run, I got an error that noted that annotations were not allowed in my JRE version (1.4). Hence, I set my JRE to 1.6 and my compiler compliance level to 1.6.

However, I now get this new error.

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Java compiler level does not match the version of the installed Java project facet.
Myprojectname       Unknown Faceted Project Problem (Java Version Mismatch)
```

How do I change "the version of the installed Java project facet"?

There is no item called "Project Facet" to the left of my project's properties menu.

Comment: If you're just starting with GAE.. I would strongly recommend to you to drop Eclipse and Java and check out the Python instead.. https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/ It is much easier when it comes to deal with datastore... ;)

Comment: Oh really? I actually developed Django apps before, and haven't coded much in Java... so I might actually do that. Thanks :) Would Java jive better with other Google tools such as the Closure library though?

Comment: Closure library is just a JavaScript library so has nothing to do with your backend. I'm not familiar with it, but my guess is that you would have the same issues if you would like to integrate it with your Java GAE version.. Your client side could be anything.. Jinja2 is the preferred over Django for templates in Python 2.7.. but on top of that anything you want..!

Comment: If you went trough the Getting Started and you liked it.. you could check out the GAE Init project... (disclaimer, I'm the creator) http://gae-init.appspot.com/

Comment: Wow, you're awesome! I'll check these projects out.